# Chrome Extension : Capture network log without opening developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, developer-tools

For Chrome to capture network log, it is compulsary to open developer tools. I am making a chrome extension in which I will need network log information. Also, how can I access captured network log through my chrome extension.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger). You can attach to an app without the Dev Tools opened.

Debugger protocol docs, in particular Network-related, can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/network).

For an example, see [Live HTTP Headers](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#live-http-headers) sample extension.

Comment: And the web request notification apis as well

Comment: @ZigMandel `webRequest` has problems with cached content, and I suppose (but cannot confirm) that debug logs are more verbose.

Comment: @Xan : sorry but I can't understand how could I use `debugger API` to get network request sent. For eg : I want each network request's `Request URL` which are of type `image/gif`.

Comment: Have you looked at the example? By the way, _requests_ are not of type `image/gif`, _responses_ are.